# Does Islam have a hermetic background from ancient Babylon?

Tags: history, theology

Does Islam have a hermetic background from ancient Babylon? If not, then why does it copy the philosophy and rituals from them? Especially the astrological principles laid down by that priesthood of Babylonia.

Comment: yes, this is the expected way, also plz feel free to cover the [help centre](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help),

Comment: u need to provide some examples as to which things specifically do you want to compare? other wise it is **too broad**. and also cover this [on topic](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Yes indeed... The philosophy of monotheism is essentially pagan, which means that everyone/everything get effected by the same principle cause. The use of archetypal characteristics of heavenly bodies, such as Moon worship in the form of Salaat ritual, Saturn worship=30 day fasting, Jupiter worship=Zakat, Venus worship=Hajj, Sun worship=Tawaf around Kaaba, Mars worship=Fighting Jihad, and ritual ablution for prayers and recitation of Quran=Mercury. Also the Quran swears by the heavens, Stars, Sun, Moon, Sirius (Sura Najm), talks of destruction by the four elements (air, earth, water, fire) etc

Comment: It is you made that up, I haven't seen such an analogy before... & moreover, how is this possible "The philosophy of monotheism is essentially pagan", my dictionary defines pagan as "belonging to a religion which worships many gods, especially one which existed before the main world religions"

Answer (score 1):

There are two major claims about the religion history:

1. Atheistic view
2. Islam's view

**Atheistic View**

It says that the humans were afraid of natural events such as lightning and storm. Also they were thankful for other natural things such as fruit giving trees. So, with the improvement of the brain and abstract thinking, they started to give abstract meanings to natural things and events, which eventually led them to worship in order to gain favor and avoid disasters. In time, with an improved abstract thinking and tools, humans realized that ordinary natural things can be beaten, thus they must be controlled by more powerful beings: gods. In time, this polytheism evolved into monotheism. Thus, it is expected that today's monotheistic believes still carrying myths from past.

**Islam's View**

It says that, there are always One God, there was and there will be. He created mankind and gave orders, but mankind corrupted the fact. Thus, Allah chose messengers among people in order to remind them the fact. Some were successful, some weren't. But, eventually mankind changed the belief again by corrupting the belief and changing the books which were given to the prophets by Allah to teach them the truth. Eventually, the last messenger was chosen and he was given a book which will never be changed until the end of the world. The belief in the minds can be corrupted again as we can see today, but one who seeks for truth can reach it through un-corrupted book.

**Conclusion**

If you believe that the atheistic claim is true, then you won't be surprised by the signs of the ancient beliefs in today's religions.

But, if you believe that the Islam's claim is true, then you won't be surprised by the signs of ancient beliefs in Islam, because they are a part of the truth and they were there before the ancient polytheistic beliefs. They just entered to the polytheistic beliefs in the corruption process, they probably misunderstood, but they were there before. Islam just corrected their meanings.

> Does Islam have a hermetic background form ancient Babylon?

No, ancient Babylon has a background from Islam (the only monotheistic religion since the beginning). But, a lot of things had lost their true meaning.

> If not, then why does it copy the philosophy and rituals from them?

Ancient Babylon copied the philosophy and rituals from Islam, but changed their meanings. They probably discovered the order in the sky/planets, enlightened the bond between it and religious rituals, but with the change in their belief, this bond gained a different meaning.

Comment: It's fine... But whenever one talks of Islam, he should be clear about referring to the period after the prophet Muhammad, not before him; mainly because the Islam of the pre-Muhammad era was Christianity and Judaism, which is a separate subject and leads to confusion.

Comment: Islam's claim about this is different. I specifically wrote "(the only monotheistic religion since the beginning)" for this. From the view of Islam, it is not a new religion revealed by Mohammad (puh) only, it was there since the beginning of mankind, even the first man (Adam(puh)) was a prophet of Islam. Thus, I am clearly not referring to the era which is after Mohammad (puh), because this question/answer needs it.

Comment: According to Islam, there is no Christianity or Judaism. Their original was Islam, but they are corrupted today and we call this corrupted versions with these names. This is Islam's claim.

Comment: Well... The Quran clearly mentions that there are good people among Ahl-e-Kitab... Nevertheless, Hermeticism is more like a philosophical perspective, and is rampant in the Quranic teachings.

Comment: Yes, the ones don't believe or practice the corrupted parts. Quran says that Allah sent a prophet for every nation/society. There may be a prophet in ancient Babylon (probably). Or, according to atheistic view, Mohammad(puh) may heard about Hermeticism and applied it while writing Quran. It looks like my answer is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You all need to do better research. There is a hermetic history to Islam pre Mohammad. Pre Mohammad there was polytheist religion where Allah was considered to be the creator of all, similar to Brahma in Hindu. There was one sect that worshipped Allah exclusively, Hanifs, and this is what spawned monotheistic Islam. There are some excellent texts on this subject that delve into the science of magic in relation to Islam, relative to Kabbalah thought.